# Guava - how to avoid event chaining in nice way?

Tags: java, guava, event-bus

Let's say I have two events:

```
class Event1 {

}
class Event2 {
    String returnValue;
}

@Subscribe
void listenTo(Event1 ev1) {
   Event2 ev2=new Event2();
   bus.post(ev2);
   //ev2.returnValue here is null
}

@Subscribe
void listenTo(Event2 ev) {
   ev2.returnValue="returnValue";
}
```

When I call

```
 bus.post(new Event1());
```

the handler

```
void listenTo(Event2 ev) { ... }
```

is executed after execution of handler

```
void listenTo(Event1 ev1) { ... }
```

is finished. This is because eventBus processes events in queue. The result is that I can't have `ev2.returnValue` computed - it is null. How can I modify this code in elegant way to have second handler executed directly when `bus.post(ev2);` I want to keep code loosely coupled.

Answer (score 0):

EventBus (or any event driven architecture) is there to decouple components, extend system without changing existing parts, e t.c. What you are trying to do is to couple 2 events together, which is erroneous, and misguiding.

Events should be immutable, so that you could run them in parallel with different listeners, and get same results all the time (otherwise your results might become random from run to run, because of the sequence of listeners execution).

Saying all that you can do following:

1. Use AsyncEventBus for processing:

   http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/AsyncEventBus.html

   There is an **AsyncEventBus**, which dispatches events in ThreadPool Executor, so your **Event2** might run in parallel with **Event1** (might not guaranteed, since threads might be busy), and you can have some wait logic to read **Event2**.
2. You might have a direct call to your **Event2** logic.
3. Trigger 3rd event **Event3**, when you want to communicate something to **Event1** listener, and **make all events immutable**.

I would go with 3rd solution.